# Working with enumerations and passing it in my web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution and also a WCF service for data access. In my WebUI I have some enums like this:

```
public enum CompanyColumsEnumViewModel
{
    CompanyName,
    CompanyPostCode,
    CompanyCity
}
```

This enum allows me to perform a search based on specific columns. For example: searching for '2000' in the CompanyPostCode field.

When a user submit a search formular, I call my service and I pass several parameters like this:

```
var companies = _requestServiceClient.GetCompanies(term, column);
```

Where term = '2000' and column = 'CompanyPostCode'

**My question is** what is the best:

- pass column as en enumeration in the web service? (1)
- pass column as simple string in my web service? (2)

  (1) IEnumerable< Company> GetCompanies(string term, CompanyColumsEnumViewModel column)

  (2) IEnumerable< Company> GetCompanies(string term, string column)

If I work with enumerations I have to declare these enumerations on both side: one in my WebUI and one in my web service?

Thanks.

Comment: Should just be able to use the enumeration. Did you set your web service as a Service Reference in your web UI project? The enumeration should have been generated (check Reference.cs under Reference.svcmap in your Service Reference).

Comment: Yes my service is set as 'Service reference'. Where do I have to declare enum in my service? In my interface? In a separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your enum is part of your ServiceContract (as in it exists as a parameter) then you need to attribute it up as a `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract]
public enum CompanyColumsEnumViewModel
{
    [EnumMember]
    CompanyName,

    [EnumMember]
    CompanyPostCode,

    [EnumMember]
    CompanyCity
}
```

Then, you can discover this in a service reference on the client side.  This, I think, would be prefered to a string column.

Comment: +1 for explicit example. @Bronzato, [Here's the MSDN page on using data contracts.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll take a look at the MSDN page.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your enum as normal in a separate file.  Custom objects can explicitly be given defined data contracts and members, but if the enum is exposed as a parameter in a WCF service, then WCF is smart enough to go back and serialize it out to the WSDL itself.

This works the same for all types. If you have a class as a parameter in a WCF method, and that class has this enum as a property, then the class and the enum would both be exposed through the WSDL, and would be auto-generated on the client.